# Is this proof of $\Vert A\Vert=\Vert A^{\dagger}\Vert$ right?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $A$ be some linear operator in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and let $A^{\dagger}$ be the corresponding adjoint operator. When I look in the literature, I find that the proof of the statement $\Vert A\Vert=\Vert A^{\dagger}\Vert$ is always done by showing first that $\Vert A\Vert\leq\Vert A^{\dagger}\Vert$ and then $\Vert A\Vert\geq\Vert A^{\dagger}\Vert$.

I am just wondering why noone proves the statement directly. Is there something wrong with this proof?:

I am using that $\Vert A\Vert:=\sup_{x\in \mathcal{H},\Vert x\Vert\leq 1}\Vert Ax\Vert$ and the formula $\Vert x\Vert=\sup_{y\in\mathcal{H},\Vert y\Vert\leq 1}\vert\langle x,y\rangle\vert$.

Then we have:

$$\Vert A^{\dagger}\Vert=\sup_{x\in \mathcal{H},\Vert x\Vert\leq 1}\underbrace{\Vert A^{\dagger}x\Vert}_{\sup_{y\in\mathcal{H},\Vert y\Vert\leq 1}\vert\langle A^{\dagger}x,y\rangle\vert}=\sup_{x\in \mathcal{H},\Vert x\Vert\leq 1}\sup_{y\in \mathcal{H},\Vert y\Vert\leq 1}\vert\underbrace{\langle A^{\dagger}x,y\rangle}_{=\langle x,Ay\rangle}\vert=\sup_{y\in \mathcal{H},\Vert y\Vert\leq 1}\bigg (\underbrace{\sup_{x\in \mathcal{H},\Vert x\Vert\leq 1}\vert\langle x,Ay\rangle\vert}_{=\Vert Ay\Vert}\bigg)=\sup_{y\in \mathcal{H},\Vert y\Vert\leq 1}\Vert Ay\Vert=\Vert A\Vert$$

Comment: You should decide whether to use $A^{\ast}$ or $A^{\dagger}$. Your proof is correct (it would be appropriate to say why the switching of the suprema is legitimate if one can't count on everybody knowing that), and standard. If my memory doesn't deceive me, I've seen it far more often than proofs proving the two inequalities.

Comment: Ok great, thanks!

Comment: @DanielFischer Can't you always swap sups?  Isn't $\sup_{u\in U}\sup_{v\in V} f(u,v)=\sup_{(u,v)\in U\times V} f(u,v)$ without qualification, and so unlike integration or limits, $\sup$ just automatically commutes, regardless of context?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, you can always do that. Suprema are much better-behaved than limits, sums, integrals in that respect. But since one cannot always swap everything, it's useful to point out when one can.